# Discordjs runs on local server, but not on remote server or raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, local

Whenever I run the program on my local server it outputs: `Logged in as Meme24/7#9900!`
and whenever I give it a command, it gives an answer but whenever I put it on any other server (pi/lightsail) it outputs `Logged in as Meme24/7#9900!` but whenever I give it a command, it doesn't reply, I have tried putting a console.log to the

```
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log('message received')
})
```

and the output "message received" isnt showing up

pls help i have been facing this issue for hours now

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i needed to use

```
const client = new Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});
```

To listen for messages